# I have two gmail accounts and I want to delete one entirely. How do I do so?

Tags: gmail, account-management, delete

I have two Gmail accounts and I want to delete one entirely.  How do I do so?

Answer (score 1):

- Sign in to the account you want to delete.
- Go to [MyAccount.Google.com](https://myaccount.google.com).
- Click on "[Delete your account or services](https://myaccount.google.com/preferences#deleteservices)" under Account Preferences.
- Click "Delete Google Account and data". Confirm it's your account. Follow the rest of the process.

Your account will be inaccessible, and the data will be permanently gone in a few weeks.

Comment: This answer is very clear but it doesn't work for me. When I click  "Delete Google Account and data" I am asked for another account to which the data can be sent, and it can't be a google account. I don't want to keep the data but there seems to be no way to say to throw it away, and I don't have a non-gmail email account.

Comment: Clarification: I get the following dialog: "To continue to use your other Google services with this account - like Google Play, Docs, or Calendar - you'll need an address to sign in with. It can't be a Gmail address." But I don't want to continue using other services with this account, and there's no way to get past the dialog without entering a non-google email.